# Returning to menu from another menu?

Tags: c++

I've created a menu to call different programs. My 5th program also has a menu inside it to carry out different functions.

What I would like to know is how can I allow the user to exit program 5 and return the original main menu. Seems like I should know this...

Here is an example of my code:

MAIN MENU:

```
int main() {
while (true)
{
    system("cls");
    int option = menuOption();

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1: Program1(); break;
    case 2: Program2(); break;
    case 3: Program3(); break;
    case 4: Program4(); break;
    case 5: Program5(); break;
    default: return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
}
return 0;
}
```

PROGRAM 5 MENU:

```
void Program5() {
int score, selection;
string player;

while (true)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\t   Menu\n\t==========\n";
    cout << "1. Add a player and score\n";
    cout << "2. Show top 10 players & scores\n";
    cout << "3. Search for a player\n";
    cout << "4. Remove a player\n";
    cout << "5. Exit to main menu\n";
    cout << "\t==========\n";
    cout << "Option: \n";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;

    switch (selection)
    {
    case 1:
        //Doesn't matter
    case 2:
        //Doesn't matter
    case 3:
        //Doesn't matter
    case 4:
        //Doesn't matter
    case 5:
        return;
        break;
    default: exit(1);
    }
    system("pause");
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, remove those `system(pause)` calls from `main` and `Program5` functions.  Then remove that `exit(1)` statement in your `Program5` function as well.  Your code should just work after that.

Comment: @selbie just curious. Isn’t it not wise to not have a default, generally speaking?

Comment: @sethFrias you should not exit(1) if the user's selection is invalid, but rather inform him that the selection he made is invalid and let him try again

Comment: @sethFrias - There are no hard and fast rules on whether a `default` case statement is needed or is a best practice. It all depends on what you want the default experience or code path to be.

Comment: @selbie ah I see. Also, removing the pauses still doesn't redirect to the main menu after selecting option 5

Comment: Ok, what does it do then?

Comment: @selbie it exits the program entirely

Comment: Probably because you haven't removed all those `exit` statements. Post your complete program including your `menuOption` function which is referenced above.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `system("pause");` statements and `default: exit(1);` statement. You do not want to exit the program.
After that, according to your code, it should return to `main` and do another iteration of the while loop asking for menu option.

Answer (score 0):

By returning, you get back to main. For example, this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Program1(){

}

void Program2(){

}

void Program3(){

}

void Program4(){

}

void Program5(){
    int score, selection;
    string player;

    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\t   Menu\n\t==========\n";
        cout << "1. Add a player and score\n";
        cout << "2. Show top 10 players & scores\n";
        cout << "3. Search for a player\n";
        cout << "4. Remove a player\n";
        cout << "5. Exit to main menu\n";
        cout << "\t==========\n";
        cout << "Option: \n";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            //Doesn't matter
        case 2:
            //Doesn't matter
        case 3:
            //Doesn't matter
        case 4:
            //Doesn't matter
        case 5:
            return;
            break;
        default: exit(1);
        }
        system("pause");
    }
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        cout << "In main():\n";
        int option;
        cin >> option;

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: Program1(); break;
        case 2: Program2(); break;
        case 3: Program3(); break;
        case 4: Program4(); break;
        case 5: Program5(); break;
        default: return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives this output:

```
In main():
5


           Menu
        ==========
1. Add a player and score
2. Show top 10 players & scores
3. Search for a player
4. Remove a player
5. Exit to main menu
        ==========
Option: 
5

In main():
```

Comment: Little confused what you mean. So its returning to main, but not displaying the menu?

Comment: Replace the "In Main" with the menu. I didn't out the menu in the main so its not displayed. @sethFrias .  When you return from a function, the execution begins from the place the function is called. So when you return from Program 5, it goes back to case 5 of the switch case. It breaks and then continues the while loop